# What does "\a\11\s" in an Azure DevOps file path mean?

Tags: azure-devops, path

I just started working in Azure DevOps and I keep seeing this combination `C:\a\11\s` or `D:\a\11\a` at the beginning of file paths. When I search to find out what it means I get no results. The `C` or `D` is a "drive" reference, but what is this part `\a\11\s` or `\a\11\a` of the path referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of DevOps. The `a` is short for `agent`, the `11` is the numerical ID of a specific agent (there might be multiple on one machine) and the `s` is short for `source` (directory with sources being built) and `a` is short for `artifacts` (i.e. the build results). The short names have been chosen to prevent build failures due to too long paths.

For example, underneath `..\s` there is the complete directory tree of the source, which could be deep and use long directory and file names.

Tools used in the build process might have issues with paths longer than 255 characters.

This approach does not prevent this, but makes it less likely than if they had choosen verbose directory names.

The directories are also available by [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). For Example `Build.SourcesDirectory` or `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a local working folder on the pipeline agent machine. A search for e.g. "pipeline agent working folder" might find some info.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I am not finding any information so far that is helping me interpret those paths.